# Selecionando vários campos de uma tabela com um termo na pesquisa

Tags: php, mysql, orientação-a-objetos, codeigniter, algoritmo-de-busca

Tentei seguir uns passos que achei aqui no fórum más não deram certos...

Tenho esse código aqui no Model feito em codeigniter:

```
 // buscando clientes
     $this->db->like('nomeCliente',$termo);
     $this->db->limit(20);
     $data['clientes'] = $this->db->get('clientes')->result();

     // buscando os
     $this->db->like('idOs',$termo);
     $this->db->limit(20);
     $data['os'] = $this->db->get('os')->result();

     // buscando produtos
     $this->db->like('descricao',$termo);
     $this->db->limit(20);
     $data['produtos'] = $this->db->get('produtos')->result();

     //buscando serviços
     $this->db->like('nome',$termo);
     $this->db->limit(20);
     $data['servicos'] = $this->db->get('servicos')->result();
```

A minha dúvida é o seguinte: na tabela clientes, preciso que faça a pesquisa em outras colunas ao mesmo tempo, como ptoref, cidadec através um termo.

Por exemplo: O usuário do sistema, procura um termo de nome "dako", e ele quer saber todas as OS´s e clientes que estão relacionadas com "dako", seja ela produtos que ele mandou arrumar, que ele comprou e etc.

Fiz umas variações com o código acima, no qual eu repeti o bloco da tabela clientes abaixo, e apenas modifiquei a coluna, assim "teoricamente" deveria achar o nomeCliente e também a ruac, etc.

Espero ter explicado meu problema.

Comment: Só uma ressalva, este site não é um fórum,  é um [Q&A](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Perdão diegofm, me confundi. Más se puderem me ajudar nessa questão, agradeço!

Answer (score 0):

Bem simples Jardel.

Antes de realizar um `result()`, você pode incrementar como você imaginar. Exemplo:

```php
$this->db->like('nomeCliente', $termo);
$this->db->like('nomeMae', $outroTermo);
$this->db->like('nomePai', $maisUmTermo);
$this->db->limit(20);
$data['clientes'] = $this->db->get('clientes')->result();
```

> Quem realmente executa a query é o result()

Comment: obrigado amigo. Vou testar e qualquer coisa eu posto aqui.

Comment: Amigo... fiz isso que me falasse más agora não pesquisa nada... parece que não está obedecendo as outras tabelas.

Comment: Amigo Philipe Fernandes. Agradeço sua ajuda. Pra dar certo, aqui eu coloquei o or_like nos demais campos da tabela. Assim ficaria o like no primeiro campo, e nos demais or_like. Agora ficou perfeito!